# How to ensure trait bounds within a trait?

Tags: rust

If I have a trait like the following `Foo` trait

```rust
trait Foo: Bar {
  type Account: SomeTrait;
}
```

That has a trait bound that requires `Bar`

```rust
trait Bar {
  type UserId;
}
```

How can I request inside the `Foo` trait that this trait requires the `UserId` type inside the `Bar` trait to be `u32`?

Important note: I can't edit the `Bar` trait.

Comment: One way to wiggle around the problem, is to rewrite Bar into a generic trait. Usually, you want to write it like you have, but in your case, you DO WANT to be able to specify the type. So make Bar generic. `trait Bar<T> { ... }` allows you to write `trait Foo: Bar<u32> { ... }`

Comment: @BitTickler That is a solution, but I can't really change the Bar trait, any other ideas?

Comment: I hesistate to write an answer, because odds are, if I posted untested snippets, I would go wrong. And setting up a cargo project and whatnot for that is just too much of a hazzle. But if you cannot rewrite Bar, you can still do a generic `trait NarrowedBar<T>: Bar { UserId = T; }` thingy.

Comment: @BitTickler Rust has a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) exactly for this kind of reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be specified as a named generic argument: `Bar<UserId=u32>`.

```rust
trait SomeTrait {}

trait Foo: Bar<UserId=u32> {
    type Account: SomeTrait;
}

trait Bar {
    type UserId;
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=00d50c0f66f6139464a745f1c91f7362).

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html (wall of text) should make it easier to find this neat trick.